# Mini DisplayPort to DVI/VGA Adaptor for projectors

Tags: macbook-pro, vga-adapter, video-adapter

I was wondering if anyone could gimme some advice on buying a "mini-displayport to VGA adaptor" for my MAC BOOK PRO 13" to use with projectors for presentation purposes. The Apple price for the [product](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB572Z/B/mini-displayport-to-vga-adaptor) is $29 while I can buy it cheap from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HU39BS). However, many reviews are against buying the $10 Amazon product as its inferior to that of the original Apple product. Any suggestions other than Amazon?

I'd also like to know about the quality of "Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adaptor" compared to VGA. I don't know if they are also widely used in projectors. Thanks.

Comment: You definitely want a  VGA adaptor, not a DVI adaptor.  Every projectors you're ever likely to run into will have a VGA connection, whereas many do not have a DVI connection.  You don't want to be somewhere and be stuck because the projector only has a VGA cable, but you don't have a VGA adaptor.  VGA is the universal standard, for projectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the original one and it works just great. From my experience, ~99% of the projectors have a VGA port, some DVI. To be on the safe side, I would rather pick VGA than DVI if I'd had to choose one. I cannot say much about the non-official VGA adaptor, but I am using the original VGA adaptor for years now, and I am completely satisfied. But I also have a non-Apple Displayport to HDMI that is very reliable (Rocketfish).

In theory, DVI should have better quality than VGA if the beamer provides the appropriate output, though, since the former transmits the signal digitally, and VGA is analog. Principally, DVI is HDMI without sound.

I can remember some colleagues complaining that their generic once were sometimes not recognized. But this could also have other reasons and happen with the original one.

Comment: I once brought a DVI one and found out that damn old projector doesn't have a DVI port.